# Use existing database entry for foreign key in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Given already persisted objects for categories. How do one reuse the existing categories in a one-to-many relationship in new objects when only the id of the cateories is known

```
/** @Entity() */
class Category {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;
    /** @var  string
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id()
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Category constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $id
     */
    public function __construct($name, $id)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id   = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And now I have lets say two categories id=1 -> fiction and id=2 -> english book.
Now I know the ids of the categories and want to save the one-to-many relations in my Book object.

```
/** @Entity() */
class Book {
    /** @var  mixed
    * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany()
     */
    private $categories;
    /** @var  string */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Book constructor.
     * @param mixed $categories
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function __construct($categories, $title)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;
        $this->title      = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create and persist a book object by hand with references an existing and already persisted object from which I do only know the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this without retrieving at least a `Reference` proxy :

```
$categoriesRefs = ['english' => 1, 'fiction' => 2];
$categories = [];

foreach($categoriesRefs as $ref){
   $categories[] = $em->getReference('Namespace\Entity\Category', $ref));
}

$book = new Book($categories, 'title');

$em->persist($book);
$em->flush();
```

You can store categories without fetching the whole Category objects.
Read more about [reference proxy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies).